# Add single quotes to all values in single shot

Tags: sql

Is there a way to add single quotes to many variables in single shot? For example

```
select Col1, Col2 from ccc.aaa.table
where Col3 in (ABC,
BCH,
ASD,
ASDF,
)
```

In the above example, we need to put quotes manually to all 4 values. So can we make add quotes all in single shot?

Expected output

```
select Col1, Col2 from ccc.aaa.table
where Col3 in ('ABC',
'BCH',
'ASD',
'ASDF',
)
```

Comment: This is not a "SQL" question - it's a question about the features of the editor or SQL client you are using.

Comment: I just do this with a Notepad++ macro

Comment: no need for a macro. See my answer. Just with a very easy regular expression and it works

Comment: @xavier the point of the macro is you save once and run whenever you need with one click/keyboard shortcut

Comment: yes, sure. A macro is great. I just give an option if you don't even know what a macro is... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Excel Concatenate Function. You can achieve this in a single shot for any number of records.

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/concatenate.html

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy if you use Visual Studio Code. Just have to edit multiple lines:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics

When you edit multiple lines, you can press `Home` key and introduce the first quote. Then you press `End` key, you move backwards 1 position (to avoid the `,`) and then you press the second quote:

[image]

Still another option: if you use regular expressions (many editors use them, such as NotePad++ or Visual Studio Code itself) you can substitute `^(.*),$` with `'$1',` and clean the fist row manually.

[image]

Good luck!